# switching from EnterpriseLibrary.Validation to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: .net, attributes, enterprise-library, data-annotations

I'm moving some code from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, and have come across a more complex validator that I am having trouble in changing it to DataAnnotations, anyone got any pointers on how I can convert this?

```
[NotNullValidator]
[DomainValidator("M", "F", "A", MessageTemplate = "{0} is not valid for {1}")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, you don't have to, and perhaps it's best not to, check out my other question on [Passing Validation Exceptions via WCF and Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501879/passing-validation-exceptions-via-wcf-rest)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write a custom validation extending `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` class.

More details can be found on the following question: [Custom validation with Data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905777/custom-validation-with-data-annotations)